# Simple question about boolean operator in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

The XML file I want to extract data from looks as below:

```
`<groups>
  <group>approved</group>
  <group>withdrawn</group>
</groups>`
```

I am using 'if' statement on this part of code to give me the data only if it is approved and don't give me the data if it has both groups(approved and withdrawn). I tried doing something but its not giving me the output. I tried the following:

```
<xsl:if test="groups/group='approved' and group!='withdrawn'">
<xsl:value-of select="name"/><xsl:text>
```

I also tried other things, but couldn't really get there. If anyone can help me with this simple question that will be really great. Thank you.

Comment: After "group!=" you have two quotes ' '.

Comment: Don't worry, just wanted to know if it was a typo or else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using 'if' statement on this part of code to give me the data
>   only if it is approved and don't give me the data if it has both
>   groups(approved and withdrawn).

I guess that you're looking for something like:

```
<xsl:if test="groups/group='approved' and not(groups/group='withdrawn')">
    <!-- some stuff -->
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Correct answer. Note the difference between `A != B` and `not(A = B)`. The first is true if there is an A that is not equal to B; the second is true if there is no A that is equal to B.

Comment: @all Thank you for your help. And, also thank you for sharing the knowledge. This really help me understands the concepts. Thank you.